# Blank 'Exception Handled' dialog in Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I'm making a Node.js app in VS 2017 using `Node.js Tools for Visual Studio`. When an exception happens, I get an empty `Exception Unhandled` dialog, does anyone know how to correct this? I want to know what the exception is or it's description, so that I can fix it.

[image]

Comment: Given how few programmers complain about this (well, none), you have to assume this is a localized problem.  If you don't want to spin the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune then consider using Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I'll report. It's good to know that this could be a bug after all, I was starting to think that this is normal for NodeJS apps (haven't made them before).

Answer (score 0):

You probably should handle the exception. If you want your program to fail with an error, then it's working as intended and you silence the VisualStudio warning with a pragma like this :

`#pragma Exception Unhandled`

Comment: But I want to know what the exception was, so that I can fix it. The space inside the box is where it shows the exception name/description when developing with say C# .

Comment: You're launching the exception yourself, it's an "Error". The function errors.x() is probably a custom string to explain what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks but I think this is an error with Visual Studio's integration with it's Node Tools extension. All the exception handling messages are blanked out and even Intellisense doesn't work for most node modules.